# Algorithm for node assignment in graph

Tags: algorithm, optimization, graph, language-agnostic

There are `N` nodes (1 ≤ `N` ≤ 2⋅10^5) and `M` (1 ≤ `M` ≤ 2⋅10^5) directed edges in a graph. Every node has an assigned number (an integer in the range 1...`N`) that we are trying to determine.

All nodes with a certain assigned number will have directed edges leading to other nodes with another certain assigned number. This also implies that if one node has multiple directed edges coming out of it, then the nodes that it leads to all have the same assigned number. We have to use this information to determine an assignment of numbers such that the number of distinct numbers among all nodes is maximized.

Because there are multiple possible answers, the output should be the assignment that minimizes the numbers assigned to nodes 1…`N`, in that order. Essentially the answer is the lexicographically smallest one.

Example:

In a graph of 9 nodes and 12 edges, here are the edges. For the two integers `i` and `j` on each line, there is a directed edge from `i` to `j`.

```
3 4
6 9
4 2
2 9
8 3
7 1
3 5
5 8
1 2
4 6
8 7
9 4
```

The correct assignment is that nodes 1, 4, 5 have the assigned number `1`; nodes 2, 6, 8 have the assigned number `2`; and nodes 3, 7, 9 have the assigned number `3`. This makes sense because nodes 1, 4, 5 lead to nodes 2, 6, 8, which lead to nodes 3, 7, 9.

To solve this problem, I thought that you could create a graph with disconnected subgraphs each representing a group of nodes that have the same assigned number. To do this, I could simply scan through all the nodes, and if a node has multiple directed edges to other nodes, you should add them to your graph as a connected component. If some of the nodes were already in the graph, you could simply add edges in between the current components.

Then, for the rest of the nodes, you could find which nodes they have directed edges to, and somehow use that information to add them to your new graph.

Would this strategy work? If so, how can I properly implement the second portion of my algorithm?

EDIT 1: Earlier I interpreted the problem statement incorrectly; I have now posted the correct interpretation and my new way of approaching the problem.

EDIT 2: So once I go through all the nodes once, adding edges in the way I described above, I would determine the components for each node. Then I would iterate through the nodes again, this time making sure to add the rest of the edges into the graph recursively. For example, if a node with an assigned number has a directed edge to a node that hasn't been assigned a number, I can add that node to its designated component. I can also use Union Find to maintain the components.

While this will be fast enough, I'm worried that there may be errors - for example, when I do this recursive solution, it is possible that when a node is assigned a number, other nodes with assigned numbers that are connected to that node may not work with it. Basically, there would be a contradiction. I would have to come up with a solution for that.

Comment: node 4 and 5 have common ancestor node 3 so ok for them to be of the same value.
Why should node 1 be assigned the same value as node 4/5?

Comment: For the example, I used the sample case given in the problem statement. In the solution for the sample case, node 1 was assigned the same value as nodes 4 and 5. I'm not sure why lol - it is possible that this was done for it to be lexicographically smaller.

Comment: you wrote yourself ```determine an assignment of numbers such that the number of distinct numbers among all nodes is maximized```. So it would make sense to give node 1:1 value, node 2,6,8:2 value, node 3,7,9: 3 value and node 4,5: 4 value
please clarify the problem? (Note that the same question applies to 8, why it is in the same class as 2,6, and why 9 in the same class as 3,7)

Comment: I took the wording exactly from the problem statement. I have the same confusion over how the values for 8 and 9 were assigned, and I was hoping someone could clarify for me as well why that’s why they were assigned - I’ll try to ask but could you determine how you would group the nodes into groups with the same assigned number?

Comment: you just need to consider a graph G and make an edge between nodes which share the same value. Then count the disconnected subgraphs

Comment: you should not ask questions in comment. we should, - to ask you clarification on your problem -. If you don't understand what is disconnected subgraphs (and you should look it on stack there are resources), then you should ask a very specific question about it on its appropriate post. However I think it is premature and you should come up to algo + code because it doesn't feel like you spent that much time so far

Comment: @grodzi, I edited the problem description

Comment: you can still give node 1 an isolated value like 4, which makes more than 3 values as you propose. @elenora

Comment: Ok so all nodes with one assigned number have directed edges leading to nodes of another assigned number. So node 1 leads to 2, which is in the same component as 6. Since node 4 leads to 6, 1 must be in the same component as 4.

Comment: why is 2 in the same component as 6... Better ask your teacher to clarify or directly post the original exercise!

Comment: Node 2 is in the same component because node 4 has directed edges to nodes 2 and 6. Like I explained in the problem statement, if one node has multiple edges leading out of it, the nodes it leads to all have the same assigned number.

Answer (score -1):

For each node, print rand() % rand() + 1 and pray. With dedication, you might pass all cases.